# Question related to self adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $S$ be a self-adjoint operator and $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $E$.

> I look for a suitable conditions under which $AP=PA$? where $P$ is the orthogonal projection into $\overline {\mbox{Im}(S)}$.

I think that, if $\mbox{Ker}(S)$ and $\mbox{Ker}(S)^\perp$ are invariant subspaces for $A$ then $AP=PA$.

In fact, every $x\in E$ can be written as $x = y + z$ with $y\in\overline {\mbox{Im}(S)}$ and $z\in \mbox{Ker}(S)$. Hence $Px=Py+Pz=y$. Clearly $APx=Ay$. Moreover since $\mbox{Ker}(S)$ and $\mbox{Ker}(S)^\perp$ are invariant subspaces for $A$ then $PAx=PA(x+y)=P(Ay)+P(Az)=P(Ay)=Ay$. So, $PA=AP$.

> Do you think that we can get a more suitable conditions under which $AP=PA$?.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P'=1-P$ be the projection onto $\ker(S)^\perp=\overline{\mathrm{im}(S)}$. Note that $AP=PA$ is equivalent to $AP'=P'A$. Now lets follow that from $AP=PA$ we get that $A$ leaves $\ker(S)=\ker(P)$ invariant. The same argument with $P'$ shows that $A$ leaves $\overline{\mathrm{im}(S)}$ invariant. Thus the conditions you have written up are both necessary and sufficient for equation $AP=PA$ to hold.

The implication
$$AP=PA\implies A(\ker(P))\subset \ker(P)$$
follows like this, let $x\in \ker(P)$ then $A(Px)=0$, but this is equal to $P(Ax)$ so $Ax\in \ker(P)$.

Comment: I think that $P'$ is the projection onto $Ker(S)$ because $P$ is the projection onto $Ker(S)^\perp$

Comment: Oh, I mixed it up, I thought $P$ was supposed to be the projection onto $\ker(S)$.